# Что такое удаление данных?

Tags: файлы, память, файловая-система

Что вообще представляет собой удаление данных с диска или с другого носителя информации? Каким образом высвобождается память в RAM? Что вообще такое "используемая и свободная (неиспользуемая) память"?

Comment: Слишком много вопросов, при чем достаточно абстрактных. Если по каждому из них дать развернутый ответ, то получится целая книга

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях все сводится к тому, что есть некие управляющие структуры (специальные области диска или ОЗУ) в которых указано, что для чего используется. Соответственно "удаление/освобождение" это запись в эти структуры информации о том, что такие то блоки свободны. А конкретика зависит используемой файловой системы, в случае диска. Или менеджера памяти (ОС или библиотек программы).